# No gradient problem when modifying model's weights with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient

When I was trying to add a perturbation to a model and optimize the perturbation itself but not the model parameters. I did like the following, which is very simple:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

# Define a simple model
class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x, perturbation, clean):
        self.linear.weight.data = perturbation + clean
        return self.linear(x) 

# Generate clean dataset
X = torch.tensor([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]], dtype=torch.float32)
Y = 2 * X

# Create the model
model = SimpleModel()

# Define perturbation as a separate parameter
perturbation = torch.tensor(0.1, requires_grad=True)
clean = model.linear.weight.data
# Train the model and optimize the perturbation
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer_perturbation = optim.SGD([perturbation], lr=0.01)  # Optimize the perturbation

for epoch in range(100):
    optimizer_perturbation.zero_grad()

    outputs = model(X,clean,perturbation)
    loss = criterion(outputs, Y)
    loss.backward()
    # Update the perturbation
    optimizer_perturbation.step()
```

However, the gradient of perturbation was still None after executing loss.backward(). I cannot figure out why. What caused this problem and what should I do to realize the result I needed?

I think perturbation.grad shouldn't be None after executing loss.backward() but it was.

```
#before executing loss.backward()
model.linear.weight.grad
None
perturbation.grad
None
#after executing loss.backward()
perturbation.grad
None
model.linear.weight.grad
tensor([[-26.8524]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `.data` attribute isn't tracked by autograd. You need something like `return nn.functional.linear(x, perturbation + clean)`

Comment: Yeah, it really helps! But it means I need to reconstruct all the layers' forward function if I need to use a bigger model. That may not be suitable in the practical situations. Waiting for better answers.

Comment: I found it's not complicated at all, at least for DNN and CNN